# How do I brute-force a md5 hash?

Tags: c, hash, openssl, md5

I'm a little confused on my current task which is to brute-force a md5 hash. I'm also allowed to reduce the hash value down to 24 bits for learning purposes and I'm using OpenSSL in C to generate the md5 hash. My problem is I don't understand the exact method of brute-forcing it, what I did try is:

Check every ascii character append it and then hash it, then compare it to the target hash.

If this is the correct way to brute-force a hash, then how do I go about reducing it down to 24 bits (because then the hash would be changed)?

Comment: Yes, just iterate through all possible input strings until you find one whose hash collides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Reducing to 24 bits” for the sake of the exercise means that instead of looking for an input `X` such that `md5(X)=<128 target bits (fixed)>`, you can instead solve the simpler problem of looking for `X` such that `md5(X)=<124 unconstrainted bits><24 target bits>`.

In other words, the test for deciding whether you have reached your objective is more lenient.

---

“Brute-force” means methodically trying all inputs until you find one that satisfies the condition. If you were testing alphabetical words, that would for instance mean testing `a`, `b`, ..., `z`, `aa`, `ab`, `ac`, ... (but there is no reason to limit yourself to alphabetical words, you can try all binary messages of length 1, 2, …)